# Google Web Toolkit Runtime error: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

I am doing my first steps in GWT and I am fascinated by the possibilities.

So far I have set up a small project that relies on java classes supplied in a external library. This library is made available to my project via maven (own repository).
I want to use Java classes from that library on the client side - so I had to supply the source code within the jar and had to make sure, those classes do not use code that's not translateable to Javascript.

So far so good. I finally got past the errors that no source code could be found.. Now a new error arises during runtime of the web application:

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent
Code attribute in method that is not
native or abstract in class file
javax/persistence/LockModeType
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native
Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native
Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2670)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1603)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.TypeOracleMediator.createAnnotation(TypeOracleMediator.java:463)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.TypeOracleMediator.resolveAnnotationValue(TypeOracleMediator.java:725)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.TypeOracleMediator.resolveAnnotationValue(TypeOracleMediator.java:681)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.TypeOracleMediator.createAnnotation(TypeOracleMediator.java:474)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.TypeOracleMediator.resolveAnnotation(TypeOracleMediator.java:640)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.TypeOracleMediator.resolveAnnotations(TypeOracleMediator.java:655)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.TypeOracleMediator.resolveClass(TypeOracleMediator.java:801)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.TypeOracleMediator.addNewTypes(TypeOracleMediator.java:416)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.TypeOracleMediatorFromSource.addNewUnits(TypeOracleMediatorFromSource.java:54)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationState.assimilateUnits(CompilationState.java:164)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationState.<init>(CompilationState.java:82)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.doBuildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:409)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.buildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:299)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDef.getCompilationState(ModuleDef.java:325)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase$UiBrowserWidgetHostImpl.createModuleSpaceHost(DevModeBase.java:105)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:190)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:510)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:352)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

I use Eclipse (Helios) and the Eclipse GWT-PLugin. The Web app is hosted by the internal App Server. JDK is 1.6 on Mac OS X.
Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 1):

The JDK doesn't include an implementation of the `javax.persistence` package - it's part of Java EE. Even if it did you should not be including SQL related libraries on the client side - your GWT application cannot directly query a SQL server.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jason.
I am not trying to directly query my SQL server vom the GWT client side. I simply want to reuse the class definition, so I can avoid som redundancy between core server (that deals with database persistance) and my web application.

I the meantime I found out that the problem lies with the persistence annotations. Once I provide a jar file with the annotation source, the exception goes away.

Answer (score 0):

The javaee-api is stripped code. i.e. the actual logic byte code is removed from the classes. It does not play nice with GWT

For Java EE 6, replace :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax</groupId>
  <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
  <version>6.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

With :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
  <artifactId>geronimo-ejb_3.1_spec</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
  <artifactId>geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Does not effect your deployment because it is provided.

Answer (score 0):

I will summarize my experience about this error in order to help someone (and clarify some scenarios).

As @Tom, I use eclipse and the GWT Plugin (and this means that I tend to do left click on my project > Run As > Web Application, in order to run/test my web application)...

Also, my projects are based on maven, so my GWT project was created using the maven archetype provided by the maven GWT plugin:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
...
</plugin>
```

According to the plugin documentation ([google_plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/eclipse/google_plugin.html)), the project generated by the plugin integrates perfect with GWT Eclipse Plugin; That is TRUE!

However, If your client code (the java code that is translated to javascript) includes JPA annotations (e.g. domain objects), you will reach some errors under various scenarios (here I will assume that you're using maven as me, but the conclusions can be applied to a regular project also):

**Scenario One (Compilation Errors):** you will not able to compile your GWT Application, because the compiler will complain about not know any of these annotations. If you're using maven, this problem is resolved using the dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax</groupId>
  <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
  <version>6.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

**Scenario Two (The code compiles, but you get "the absence attribute ..." Error when running the app on devmode):** As @rjdkolb pointed out, the problem resides in that the javaee-api dependency is a stripped code... So in order to get rid of the error, you should replace that dependency with a complete implementation library. I suggest that you use a library of your own application server, which in my case is JBOSS... So i put,

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
  <artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.0.GA</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

(Beware, I get that library from JBOSS nexus repository, and then I installed that library on my local MAVEN repository)...

Also make sure that the dependency appears before the gwt-user and gwt-servlet dependencies (so the dependency takes precedence over the last two)...

**Here is where the weird part appears**... IF you run your GWT Project with the gwt plugin (I mean, you use the mvn gwt:run command), you will get rid of the "the absence attribute ..." Problem...

However, if you use the Eclipse GWT plugin (Run As > Web Application), you will get still the "the absence attribute..." Problem... I don't know why, but the Eclipse Plugin doesn't seem to obey the pom dependencies completely; instead, it obeys the classpath defined in the project properties (Project Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries)

**So, in order to get rid of the error, when using the option "Run As > Web Application"**, you must add the complete library (in my case, ejb3-persistence) to the project classpath (Project Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries > Add ...) and make the library to take precedence over the GWT Eclipse Plugin Libraries (Project Properties > Java Build Path > Order and Export; it must appear before the maven dependencies and the GWT Container Library)...

Hope this help!